Does pandoc overwrite Latex headers when converting org mode document using xelatex engine?
I've setup this collection of Latex headers in an org-mode document to stylize exported PDFs. They all worked, except for settings for fourth level headers, e.g.
**** subsubsubsection
which by default appear as normal text in a numbered list
as well as settings that tried to modify style of hyperlinks, e.g.
[[https://example.com][link]]
which by default appear as normal text
does pandoc introduce some default settings for org-mode to latex/pdf conversion that override these headers?
sample block of headers with headers trying to override hyperlinks:
#+TITLE: <TITLE>
#+AUTHOR: <AUTHOR>
#+DATE: \today
#+OPTIONS: \n:t

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fontspec}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmainfont{Nimbus Sans}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{titling}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[margin=0.5in, bottom=0.8in]{geometry}  % Increased bottom margin
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{sectsty}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xcolor}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{titlesec}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fancyhdr}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{soul}  % For highlighting text
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{hyperref}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \hypersetup{
#+LATEX_HEADER:     colorlinks=true,
#+LATEX_HEADER:     linkcolor=blue,
#+LATEX_HEADER:     filecolor=magenta,      
#+LATEX_HEADER:     urlcolor=cyan,
#+LATEX_HEADER:     citecolor=blue
#+LATEX_HEADER: }
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{cyan}\hl}  % Highlight URLs with cyan background

#+LATEX_HEADER: \pagestyle{fancy}  % Use fancy page style for all pages
#+LATEX_HEADER: \fancyhf{}  % Clear all header and footer fields
#+LATEX_HEADER: \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}  % Place the page number in the right side of the footer (bottom right corner)
#+LATEX_HEADER: \fancyfoot[C]{}  % Ensure nothing is placed in the center
#+LATEX_HEADER: \fancyfoot[L]{}  % Ensure nothing is placed in the left side of the footer
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % Remove the header line
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}  % Remove the footer line

#+LATEX_HEADER: \fancypagestyle{plain}{
#+LATEX_HEADER:    \fancyhf{}  % Clear all header and footer fields
#+LATEX_HEADER:    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}  % Place the page number in the right side of the footer
#+LATEX_HEADER:    \fancyfoot[C]{}
#+LATEX_HEADER:    \fancyfoot[L]{}
#+LATEX_HEADER:    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
#+LATEX_HEADER:    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
#+LATEX_HEADER: }

#+LATEX_HEADER: \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*3}{*2}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\color{cadetblue}\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titleformat{\section}[block]{\color{darkcyan}\LARGE\bfseries}{}{1em}{}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \definecolor{darkcyan}{HTML}{008B8B}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \definecolor{cadetblue}{HTML}{5F9EA0}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \definecolor{steelblue}{HTML}{4682B4}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \definecolor{lightseagreen}{HTML}{20B2AA}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \definecolor{mediumaquamarine}{HTML}{66CDAA}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}  % Number up to the second level (subsections)
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}  % Single integer numbering with a dot for subsections
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand\thesection{}  % No numbering for sections

#+LATEX_HEADER: \sectionfont{\LARGE\bfseries}  % Font settings for the first-level headers
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titleformat{\subsubsection}{\color{steelblue}\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titleformat{\paragraph}{\color{lightseagreen}\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \titleformat{\subparagraph}{\color{mediumaquamarine}\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \posttitle{\end{center}}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \preauthor{\begin{center}\large}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \postauthor{\end{center}}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \predate{\begin{center}\large}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \postdate{\end{center}}


What pandoc does is of no concern to either Org mode or Emacs. Please don't ask pandoc questions on Emacs SE.

Have you tried without pandoc? Does the regular Org mode exporter show the problem? If not, then it's  a pandoc problem and you need to ask probably on Unix&Linux SE. But if it does (as the answer below suggests might be the case), then it's an honest-to-goodness Org question and perfectly appropriate for this site. But you need to tells us what's true: we are just guessing here.

@NickD you are right, running regular Org mode exporter doesn't have the problem with links styles emacsclient -n -e '(progn (find-file "path/tot/file.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))'. I didn't think that they would behave differently when they both use xelatex under the hood (#+LATEX_COMPILER: xelatex). I can remove the question as it's too pandoc-specific

This appears not to be a pandoc issue, but an Org mode issue: If you want headers beyond the third level to be set as section, not lists, then set the H option to a higher value. E.g.
#+OPTIONS: H:6

See the Export Settings section in the manual.
